Really weird engine nozzle design
This Martin design for an Single Stage To Orbit orbital satellite Launch Vehicle was part of the High Altitude Test Vehicle (HATV) program.

Credit: © Mark Wade
http://www.astronautix.com/m/martinhatv.html
You'll notice the engine and nozzle immediately.
Whilst the Astronautix page offers some basic info, I am still rather intrigued as I can find no other reference to this engine: It's an Aerojet design, but other than that I don't have much other details.
Details details details!!!
Has this been studied as an engine form for another vehicle, and what might be its drawbacks.

What question are you asking? If you want to know everything that you put into the blockquote, you should narrow down to just one of those questions.  Some links (e.g. to the Astronautix page you refer to) might also be helpful.

Cool I'll modify thx (:

Please don't use abbreviations without including definitions. I can assume meanings for SSTO and LV but others may assume different meanings.  Google search gives LV definitions :Left ventricle, Louis Vuitton, Latvia, Livermorium, and Luncheon Voucher. Launch Vehicle is not included.

Is martin Lockheed Martin or somebody else? Please be clear. If you meant the former, please type Lockheed or the full name next time.

I would recommend these 2 links: http://www.aerospaceprojectsreview.com/blog/?p=2103 and https://www.secretprojects.co.uk/threads/martin-orbit-project-of-1946.14427/

@LawnHollanderLawn why would you assume that Martin was anyone but Martin?  The link already in the question tells you who it is.

@LawnHollanderLawn At the time it was just Martin actually. It is now Lockheed Martin. Lockheed was a separate entity

@AnarchoEngineer I apologize for the mistake.

Next time you are in there editing you may want to put 1946 in the title, i.e. "This 1946 Martin design".  Yes it's in the article but it adds important context to the topic. And it would help clear up the whole "Martin" thing.  @AnarchoEngineer - to be more specific at the time it was the Glenn L. Martin Company, which was often shortened to just Martin as it was in the linked article. In 1961 it merged with American-Marietta to become Martin Marietta, in 1995 it merged with Lockheed to became Lockheed Martin. I realize you probably know this but not everyone does.

Fair enough @StevePemberton.
I'll keep that in mind thanks!

There's a fair amount of information on this engine in Chapter 3 of NASA SP-4044 "Liquid Hydrogen as a Propulsion Fuel" https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19790008823 I don't have enough info to write an answer, but I'm pretty sure this concept was a dead end.

Do y'all think maybe this question should be closed, considering it's not garnering answer sized info.

This is the only question I see in your post "Has this been studied as an engine form for another vehicle, and what might be its drawbacks." It's going to be hard to find out if it's ever "been studied" again.
